# Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library: Upload file to document center

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a file in a Sharepoint document center using Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library. It seems that I can successfully create the file but it is not visible to anyone except the app which created it. When the app creates a file in an "ordinary" document library with exactly the same code then the file is visible to other users (as expected).

Here is the code I use:

```
var result = await client.Drives[documentCenterDriveId]
                         .Items[subfolderId]
                         .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                         .Content
                         .Request()
                         .PutAsync<DriveItem>(new MemoryStream(buffer));
```

Afterwards I can query the folder and see that the file is there:

```
var result = await client.Drives[documentCenterDriveId]
                         .Items[subfolderId]
                         .Children
                         .Request()
                         .GetAsync();
```

However when go to the Microsoft Graph Explorer, sign in with my personal credentials (i.e. not the same as the app) and issue the following GET request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/documentCenterDriveId/items/subfolderId/children
```

I get an empty list. If I do the same for the "ordinary" document library it works as expected.

I checked the permissions of the file in the document center with

```
var perms = await client.Drives[documentCenterDriveId]
                        .Items[fileId]
                        .Permissions
                        .Request()
                        .GetAsync();
```

and the `read` role is granted to a group my account belongs to. This means I should be able to see it.

How can I diagnose the source of this issue? Are there logs somewhere in Sharepoint where I could find out more? There are no error messages or exceptions when I run my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I also have to checkin the file.

```
await client.Drives[documentCenterDriveId].Items[result.Id].Checkin().Request().PostAsync();
```

I don't know why I do not need to checkin the file after upload in a "ordinary" document library but in the document center I have to.